# mount failing on /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/

Tags: bash, network-manager, vpn, cifs

I have a script that tries to mount a `cifs` share when the VPN is connected (after I've already logged in to the desktop - so kerberos ticket is issued).
It's in :
`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="$1"
STATUS="$2"

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        if [ "$INTERFACE" = "vpn0" -o "$INTERFACE" = "cscotun0" ]; then
        mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
        fi
fi
```

It fails with the error in `/var/syslog`:

```
dispatcher: (82) zz-mount-dfs failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/zz-mount-dfs' exited with error status 32.
```

The script is rooot:root with 755 permissions

Yet if I run the command :

```
mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
```

from my user OR as root it works fine.

`/etc/fstab` for reference:

```
# Active Directory Home Folder
//ant/home/ad-dir/eekfonky   /home/eekfonky/homeDrive  cifs  x-systemd.device-timeout=15,cruid=eekfonky,sec=krb5,noauto,users,noserverino,vers=2.1,rw 0   0
```

EDIT:
After enabling logging I found this;

```
$ sudo dmesg
[  576.237469] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188953.283:35): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/vpn0/type" pid=1600 comm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  576.239247] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188953.287:36): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/vpn0/type" pid=1600 comm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  576.916780] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/cifsfs.c: Devname: //ant/home/ad-dir/eekfonky flags: 0
[  576.916803] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: Username: root
[  576.919659] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: file mode: 0x1ed  dir mode: 0x1ed
[  576.919662] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: in cifs_mount as Xid: 0 with uid: 0
[  576.919663] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: UNC: \\ant\home
[  576.919677] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: Socket created
[  576.919679] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: sndbuf 16384 rcvbuf 87380 rcvtimeo 0x6d6
[  577.116792] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: Demultiplex PID: 10008
[  577.116794] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/fscache.c: cifs_fscache_get_client_cookie: (0x00000000ddc65715/0x00000000371ab3e3)
[  577.116797] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: in cifs_get_smb_ses as Xid: 1 with uid: 0
[  577.116798] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: Existing smb sess not found
[  577.116803] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2pdu.c: Negotiate protocol
[  577.116808] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/transport.c: Sending smb: smb_len=102
[  577.314065] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: RFC1002 header 0xf8
[  577.314072] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2misc.c: smb2_check_message length: 0xfc, smb_buf_length: 0xf8
[  577.314074] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2misc.c: SMB2 data length 120 offset 128
[  577.314076] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2misc.c: SMB2 len 252
[  577.314087] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/transport.c: cifs_sync_mid_result: cmd=0 mid=0 state=4
[  577.314089] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/misc.c: Null buffer passed to cifs_small_buf_release
[  577.314091] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2pdu.c: mode 0x1
[  577.314092] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2pdu.c: negotiated smb2.1 dialect
[  577.314095] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/asn1.c: OID len = 10 oid = 0x1 0x3 0x6 0x1
[  577.314096] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/asn1.c: OID len = 7 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0xbb92
[  577.314097] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/asn1.c: OID len = 7 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0x1bb92
[  577.314097] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/asn1.c: OID len = 8 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0x1bb92
[  577.314098] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/asn1.c: OID len = 10 oid = 0x1 0x3 0x6 0x1
[  577.314100] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: Security Mode: 0x1 Capabilities: 0x300007 TimeAdjust: 0
[  577.314100] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2pdu.c: Session Setup
[  577.314101] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/smb2pdu.c: sess setup type 5
[  577.314105] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/cifs_spnego.c: key description = ver=0x2;host=ant;ip4=10.1.103.201;sec=krb5;uid=0x0;creduid=0x25a9dede;user=root;pid=0x26fe
[  577.342612] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126
[  577.342617] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_get_smb_ses (xid = 1) rc = -126
[  577.342620] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/fscache.c: cifs_fscache_release_client_cookie: (0x00000000ddc65715/0x00000000371ab3e3)
[  577.342625] /build/linux-WKYm23/linux-4.15.0/fs/cifs/connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_mount (xid = 0) rc = -126
[  577.342625] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
[  577.412402] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.459:37): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/run/systemd/users/631889630" pid=10027 comm="krb5_child" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  577.582719] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.631:38): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/krb5/plugins/authdata/sssd_pac_plugin.so" pid=10027 comm="krb5_child" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=631889630 ouid=0
[  577.614868] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:39): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/usr/sbin/adcli" pid=10043 comm="sssd_be" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0 target="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli"
[  577.615669] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:40): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli" name="/var/log/sssd/ldap_child.log" pid=10043 comm="adcli" requested_mask="a" denied_mask="a" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  577.615672] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:41): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli" name="/var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log" pid=10043 comm="adcli" requested_mask="a" denied_mask="a" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  577.615673] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:42): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli" name="/var/log/sssd/gpo_child.log" pid=10043 comm="adcli" requested_mask="a" denied_mask="a" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  577.615969] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:43): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli" name="/usr/sbin/adcli" pid=10043 comm="adcli" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  577.615972] audit: type=1400 audit(1575188954.663:44): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/sbin/adcli" name="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so" pid=10043 comm="adcli" requested_mask="rm" denied_mask="rm" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Comment: If your HOME directory is encrypted, it does not exist until you login, and the parent of mount point `/home/eekfonky` does not exist/ Also, "error 32" means "Broken pipe", if that helps.

Comment: @waltinator I am already logged in, just changing networks. Is there a way to get a more verbose output? I can't find one

Comment: Is there anything in `dmesg` or any of the system logs of note? Take a look at [this article](https://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/01/08/smb-mount-troubleshoot/) for CIFS logging, and then try connecting to your VPN to generate log entries.

Comment: @waltinator The exit code 32 actually comes from the `mount` command; `mount(1)` describes it as 'mount failure'.

Comment: @eekfonky: can you add a `klist` command before the `mount` command in the dispatcher script? This should indicate, which Kerberos ticket would be used for the mount command.

Comment: @Simon Sudler klist doesn't work either

Comment: @eekfonky: What is the output of the klist command?

Comment: ➜  ~ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_631889630_bAl9oh
Default principal: eekfonky@MYDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
06/12/19 09:41:15  06/12/19 19:41:15  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM
 renew until 07/12/19 09:41:15

Comment: @eekfonky from the `dispatcher.d` script?

Comment: @SimonSudler did that and it was empty after running - the plot thickens

Comment: Mhh, the only thing I can think of is, that the dispatcher scripts runs to early... The manpage stats, that the scripts run on "... state changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK turns out that dispatcher doesn't carry the kerberos credentials so I had to export the environment variable `KRB5CCNAME` in the script. So it now looks like;

```
#!/bin/bash

# Kerberos Ticket
KRB_TICKET="$(ls /tmp/krb5cc_"$(id -ru eekfonky)"_*)"
export KRB5CCNAME="$KRB_TICKET"
INTERFACE="$1"
STATUS="$2"

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        if [ "$INTERFACE" = "vpn0" -o "$INTERFACE" = "cscotun0" ]; then
        sudo -u eekfonky mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
        fi
fi
```

And this works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the mount is occurring too fast so you can try this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="$1"
STATUS="$2"

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        if [ "$INTERFACE" = "vpn0" -o "$INTERFACE" = "cscotun0" ]; then
        sleep 30
        mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
        fi
fi
```

However Network Manager might kill a script that takes too long to run so you can spin off a sleeping child and have the parent exit immediately:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="$1"
STATUS="$2"

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        if [ "$INTERFACE" = "vpn0" -o "$INTERFACE" = "cscotun0" ]; then
        sleepmount &
        fi
fi
```

Contents of `sleepmount`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 30
mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
```

If either scenario works for sleeping 30 seconds then start cutting the sleeping time in half until it breaks again. Then bump up the sleep time from there until it works again.

---

## Edit: `_netdev` needed in `/etc/fstab`

From [Amazon Elastic File System User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/troubleshooting-efs-mounting.html#automount-fails):

> ### Automatic Mounting Fails and the Instance Is Unresponsive
>
> This issue can occur if the file system was mounted automatically on
>   an instance and the `_netdev` option wasn't declared. If `_netdev` is
>   missing, your EC2 instance might stop responding. This result is
>   because network file systems need to be initialized after the compute
>   instance starts its networking.
>
> #### Action to Take
>
> If this issue occurs, contact AWS Support.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same errors as above for both methods (in logs)

Comment: @eekfonky Maybe change the logging level to DEBUG: https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/logging-messages

Comment: @eekfonky Also I revised answer with `_netdev` option in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Still the same error - also it's not an EC2, not sure why the moderator added that tag

Comment: @eekfonky I think that was my fault adding EC2. I'm pretty sure I added VPN and cifs to draw more attention to your question so experts in those fields tracking the tags would have your question highlighted for them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the ownership of the Kerberos ticket. When you mount the `cifs` driver via command line as user `eekfonky`, it works because the Kerberos ticket matches to the user. If you try to mount it as `root` it fails. With `root` user, I mean not `sudo`!

Adjust the script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` with the correct user and it should work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="$1"
STATUS="$2"

if [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then
        if [ "$INTERFACE" = "vpn0" -o "$INTERFACE" = "cscotun0" ]; then
        sudo -u eekfonky mount /home/eekfonky/homeDrive
        fi
fi
```

Comment: I had thought of that but OP already stated in the question mounting works: *"from my user OR as root it works fine."*

Comment: I am unsure of that... usually a `kinit` is required per user name. So it might work with `sudo`, but not as "real" `root` user. If you are `root`, mount can't know which Kerberose ticket to use.

Comment: That fails too with `sudo -u`